How to fix brick textures proportions on my objects?
I have been following this tutorial to make tiles; however, a problem I have it making it be able to look nice and be able to place on all sides.
From the node editor, I have tried setting it to both UV and Object for the Texture Coordinator into the Mapping. The Object setting is something I would like to use as it looks the nicest where when I assign it to two objects and put them side by side, it looks very nice and well connected but it only seems to pick and choose what faces to pick, usually on the Z-axis it seems. However, with UV, it looks messed up, even trying to mess with the UV doesn't help.
Here is the example using the UV Coordinator. As you can see, my tunnel that I made doesn't connect well with other objects.


Here is what it looks like when I use the Object coordinator. It looks well connected and just looks nicer. This is the result I want, well...almost. It doesn't seem to like to affect the sides very well. Either stretching or non-existence.


Here is the entire node setup. Apologies for it being a bit blurry. I didn't exclude the mapping since it changes twice. If you want to see the entire node system. The video of the tutorial shows the node system in higher definition.


How can I fix it so it looks nice?

"However, with UV, it looks messed up, even trying to mess with the UV doesn't help." More details around this seems important. "Messing with the UV" should exactly help. What did you try in the UV editor?

Change your material to something simple like the color grid image texture. Then you can see distortions. Eliminating distortions can be tricky, basically you need to UV unwrap correctly. In your case however it's not local distortion, just disproportion of UV islands, I think. Once you solve local distortions / overall disproportions, there's still a matter of varying scale, which you can fix by selecting all objects, going to UV editor, selecting all geometry and then from menu UV "average island scale". Watchsome tutorials on UV unwrapping and modelling, because you have a lot of overlap.

@Phrogz I have tried unwrapping it, setting it to cube projection, cylinder projection, sphere projection, and Smart UV Project.

But you have not tried manually moving the UVs of faces or groups of faces to produce the result you want, in the UV Editor panel? I resisted learning manual UV editing for a long time, but it's not really that complicated. (I'm sure there are a billion tricks I don't know, so I'm often doing it the long way, but the core tweaks, overlaying vertices and edges on the image, are pretty simple.)

Its all in the marking of seams, UV unwrapping and a little UV editing.
But first, before UV unwrapping, the XY and Z rotations of the objects should be at 0°  and the XY and Z scales should be at 1.000. Your Tunnel object has a Z scale of 0.597. This would lead to the scaling issues when Unwrapping. To fix this, in Object mode select object, > open Object menu, > Apply, > All Transforms.

Transforms applied :

Mark seams and Unwrapping.
In Edit mode mark seams along edges so that when unwrapped the UV's are distorted as little as possible.
Do a test UV unwrap: Edit mode with tunnel selected > open the UV menu and choose the basic Unwrap option.
I'm guessing a lot of the UV's will be distorted so go back to the model and add more seams and unwrap again. :)
When you think you are getting somewhere change to Viewport Shading > Material Preview mode. Then change the material to your Checker texture and the output of the Texture Coordinate node to UV. Now you can see how the texture maps to the UV's. Don't worry about parts appearing to be differently scaled work on distortions of the checker texture. Note: Distortions are alleviated by adding more seams. For a model like this the UV islands should all be aligned to the X or Y axis in the UV space.
I have included a finished .blend file with all the seams marked and unwrapped etc. Just take a close look at where I have marked the seams.

Repeat above for Entrance object.
Note. for the front faces of the Tunnels arches it is a little more complicated. In front orthographic view select one of the arch's faces > UV menu > Project from View. To get the tiles aligned to the arch shape we next need to do a second UV unwrap of the arches this time using using the Follow active Quads method. Its not differcult to do: just need to square off one of the arches UV faces ... here is a short video that explains how to:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSMpNeV0vKM
When you have the arches Uv islands straightened out select the island in the UV editor and hit the P key. The vertices of the arches UV's will have turned red indicating that they are Pinned. This means that they will not be unwrapped again unless you Unpin them first. Unpin is Alt P.
Ok now both Tunnel and Entrance are UV unwrapped etc but the scale is not the same all over the models. To fix this we need to unwrap both objects together. In object mode, select the Tunnel object then Shift select the Entrance object (both objects now selected) Go into Edit mode and select All > UV menu > Unwrap. Both objects have been unwrapped together in the UV space and unwrapped to the same scale as far as possible. The pinned arches will be differently scaled so select those two islands and scale them up/down some until the checker scale looks approximately the same as on the rest of the model.

Finally change the Material of each object to your Poolroom_Tiles_2 material and Texture Coordinate node output to UV.
Play around with the X Y Scale values in the Mapping node to get the tile size that suits you best. If necessary, you can edit, move along XY axis, and rotate individual UV islands so that they better align to each other etc. Note: It does not matter if the UV islands stray outside of the UV space.

Marking seams and UV unwrapping etc just takes a bit of patience and of course the more you do the simpler it gets. For future projects have a look for tutorials on Live UV unwrapping in Blender.

Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Very detailed and helpful.
